# Angularfire2 update all children nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In Firebase, I have this db

[miodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XksYO.png)

I want to update all the children nodes (for example the children nodes of 67-68), setting the key 'status' to 'read'.

So this is how I get items list

```
this.listaquery = db.list('https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/chat/'+this.navParams .get('chatRoom'),{
          query: {
              orderByChild: 'id',
              equalTo: this.navParams .get('id2')
          }
        });
      }
```

And I know this is the code to update a child

```
this.listaquery.update('-KnFI98Lnm-BYXxR_zoY',{status:'read'});
```

But if I want to update all the children with one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution (I don't know if it's the best one)

```
this.listaquery = db.list('https://delega-facile.firebaseio.com/chat/'+this.navParams .get('chatRoom'),{
  query: {
      orderByChild: 'id',
      equalTo: this.navParams .get('id1')
  },
  preserveSnapshot: true
});


this.listaquery
          .subscribe(snapshots => {
              snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                  this.listaquery.update(snapshot.key,{status :'read'});
                  /*
                  console.log(snapshot.key)
                  console.log(snapshot.val())
                  */
              });
          })
```